# What is the distance between the 2 ×2 identity matrix and the phase-gate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, quantum-computation

I am working through R.de Wolf lecture notes on Quantum Computing and have difficulties figuring out a certain property of matrix norms.

Consider the operator norm (induced norm on matrices) : $\|A\| = \max_{\|v\| = 1} \|Av\| $ .

Define the distance between two matrices A and B as : $\|A-B\|$.

- Given a matrix (phase gate) : $$P_\phi=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & e^{i\phi} 
  \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
  What is the distance between the 2 by 2 identity matrix and the phase gate?

With a simple calculation I ended up with :
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-e^{i\phi} 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Deriving a final condition such that the distance is $\max \sqrt{|v_2 - v_2.e^{i\phi}|^2}.$

But I am not sure how to go from here (I assumed values for $\phi$ such as $\phi = \pi$)
But I am not sure how to "cover all the cases" and how to explicitly write the distance given the unknown $v_2$ term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid maximization over the unit sphere by using the fact that the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) is equal to the largest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value). We can write the singular value decomposition of the difference of the two matrices as

$$
I - P_\phi = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1-e^{i\phi}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & r\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & e^{i\theta}\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $1-e^{i\phi}=re^{i\theta}$ and we have chosen to write singular values in the increasing$^1$ order along the diagonal of the middle matrix. Therefore,

$$
\|I-P_\phi\| = r = |1-e^{i\phi}|=\sqrt{\left(1-e^{-i\phi}\right)\left(1-e^{i\phi}\right)}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\phi}.
$$

---

<sup>$^1$ Admittedly, this goes against the prevailing convention of writing singular values in decreasing order, but the unusual convention simplifies the formula by making all three matrices diagonal.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about this fact !